# Target pseudo element of first child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to target a pseudo element I am using to change the width of a border.

I am trying to get rid of the top border (first-child)

But its not working. Is this how you target a pseudo element?

```
<div class="landingHeaderNav">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>

.landingHeaderNav a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 5%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }
:first-child {
  ::before {
    border-top:none;
  }
```

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/tysonmaynes/pen/JeVrLr

Comment: do you use sass or css?>

Comment: That's not valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In **css** you have to use as below set the element before pseudo as `.landingHeaderNav a:before`:

```css
.landingHeaderNav a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.landingHeaderNav a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 5%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
 }
.landingHeaderNav a:first-child::before {
    border-top:none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="landingHeaderNav">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>
```

In sass or **s**css use:

```
    .landingHeaderNav a {
      color: #000;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
   &:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 5%;
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
     }

    &:first-child::before {
        border-top:none;
      }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, for SCSS, just fix the missing brace and configure the stylesheet in the pen to use SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [negation pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```css
.landingHeaderNav a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.landingHeaderNav a:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 5%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="landingHeaderNav">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>
```